# get filename when reading multiple xml files in spark

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read multiple xml files in spark using

```
spark.read.text(path/*.xml,wholetext=true)
```

and after this I am parsing them using xmlTree library in python.
Unfortunately, some of the xml files that I have are wrong and have some missing closing tags. Therefore, running this command gives me an error. I would like to know which file has the issue. I can't seem to find the file in the error message. Is there a way to know the file which is wrong?

P.S I cannot use the spark-xml open-source library as it is not giving me correct results for my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will want to try `input_file_name`  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html?highlight=input_file#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name

```py
(spark
    .read
    .csv('*.csv', header=True)
    .withColumn('file', F.input_file_name())
    .show(10, False)
)

# +---+---+---+------------------------------------------------+
# |a  |b  |c  |file                                            |
# +---+---+---+------------------------------------------------+
# |1  |1  |1  |file:///Volumes/A/B/C/a.csv                     |
# |2  |2  |2  |file:///Volumes/A/B/C/a1.csv                    |
# +---+---+---+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't help me. Can you help me how to use this with my use case?

Comment: I just added a piece of code to show you how it works